# How to use Kendo ui with angular 2?

Tags: visual-studio, angular, kendo-ui, telerik

I want to use Kendo UI Grid in my angular 2 application which is developed in .net core and angular 2. I googled and found [this](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#toc-add-the-progress-npm-registry). I am trying to install Kendo UI Progress using

```
 "**npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress**"
```

command in package manager console of visual studio but it is taking too much time. I am not getting any error, any response form this command. It runs for long time. I waited for 1 hour but nothing happend. What's the issue?

Comment: hello you can see this url https://dzone.com/articles/using-kendo-ui-with-angular-2-1